# Create custom POST Method URL

Tags: ajax

How i can create custom post method url in wordpress? For Example i will send data by ajax to urls:

http://example.com/?call_option=option1
or
http://example.com/?call_option=option2

And this will execute my code in function.php (in theme folder)

```
$option = trim($_GET['call_option']);
if(empty($option)) {
    header("Location: ./404");
    die();
} else {    
    if ( $option == 'option1' ) {
        // do something 
    } else if ( $option == 'option2' ) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Ho do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress comes with built in support for using AJAX calls from within your plugins or themes functions.php.

Following is the sample example:

Javascript code:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.event-trigger', function() { 
    var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>"; //You can define this parameter globally as well.
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'youraction',
            param1: param1,
            param2: param2
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
})
```

Write the following code in plugin file or functions.php file in your theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_youraction', 'your_functionname' ); //This action calls for non-authenticated users as well
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_youraction', 'your_functionname' ); //This action calls only for authenticated user

function your_functionname() {
    //your code goes here
}
```

Refer [Ajax Example](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/) for more details.

Comment: there are also informations in the codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Have you considered using the REST-API endpoint instead of admin ajax?

Answer (score 1):

There is also another simple solution, which is using the REST-API. It returns a JSON answer which you can use in javaScript, mobile applications, and more.

First you have to register a route to your function:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to ajax search function
    register_rest_route( 'patryk/v1', '/patryk-rest-api/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'my_rest_function' 
    ) );
});
```

Now, let's write a function to return some data:

```
function my_rest_function(){
    // Return of nothing is sent
    if (!isset($_POST['call_option'])) return;
    // Else, do some calculations and return a value
    $value = $_POST['call_option'];
    // Return the value
    return $data;
}
```

Now you can access your function at `http://example.com/wp-json/patryk/v1/patryk-rest-api/`, nice and easy.

However, the response is in JSON, so you have to specify this in your front-end script:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://example.com/wp-json/patryk/v1/patryk-rest-api/', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, element) {
            // Use a loop here to output your data
        });     
    }
});
```